# Extract date from partition high_value

Tags: oracle

In the `USER_TAB_PARITIONS`, there is the attribute `HIGH_VALUE`, formatted `TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-01 00:00:00'`.

**My problem:**
I want to convert `HIGH_VALUE` into a `date` with a **simple query** (without procedure, and `HIGH_VALUE` is as long stored).

So far I could transform it with that procedure:

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS
   SELECT HIGH_VALUE, PARTITION_NAME
   FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';

   partition_date   VARCHAR2(100);
   partition_name   VARCHAR2(1000);
   date_val         DATE;
   name_val         VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   FOR c1rec IN c1 LOOP
      partition_date := 'SELECT ' || c1rec.HIGH_VALUE || ' FROM DUAL';
      partition_name := 'SELECT ' || c1rec.PARTITION_NAME || ' FROM DUAL';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE partition_date INTO date_val;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(date_val);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c1rec.PARTITION_NAME);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**My question:**
Is there any possibility to do it without a procedure? For example like:

```
SELECT HIGH_VALUE, PARTITION_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
WHERE 1=1
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
  AND HIGH_VALUE < sysdate-1;
```

Comment: @JSapkota: It's not a duplicate since the question is doing it without a procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly tweaked Sandman's code

```
WITH date_partition AS (
SELECT
    partition_name,
    extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select high_value
       FROM   USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE table_name = '''
        || t.table_name
        || ''' and PARTITION_NAME = '''
        || t.partition_name
        || ''''),'//text()') AS high_value
FROM
    user_tab_partitions t
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
 ) 
 ,final_result
  (SELECT
  partition_name,
  TO_DATE(substr(high_value,11,10),'YYYY-DD-MM') high_value
FROM
date_partition
)
 SELECT partition_name,high_value FROM final_result
 WHERE HIGH_VALUE < SYSDATE -1
 /
```

Comment: In my console, it's written ORA-01843: "not a valid month". Any idea? I have tried 'YYYY-MM-DD' but then '"day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"'

Comment: Strange What is database version?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I have set it as answer since it has helped me the most, with the answer from @sandman.

Comment: I gave credit to Sandman :-)

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?  This will help you extract the LONG into text without a procedure, but I'm not sure about what SYSDATE logic you want to limit your result set to.  You would have to play with that final WHERE clause to get the right values.

```
SELECT * from (
  SELECT PARTITION_NAME,
    extractvalue
      ( dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype
        ( 'select high_value
           from DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS where table_name = ''' || t.table_name || ''' and PARTITION_NAME = ''' || t.PARTITION_NAME || ''''),
        '//text()' ) as high_value 
  FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS t
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE')
WHERE to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'SYYYYMMDD') < high_value;
```

Comment: I have no right on DBA_TAB_PARTIONS but with USER_TAB_PARTITIONS. And it rocks. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot filter with this where clause. E.g. The timestamp TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-01 00:00:00' is not filtered. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After an epic fight, we got it:

```
WITH date_partition AS (
    SELECT  partition_name,
            TO_DATE(
                substr(
                    extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
                        'select high_value FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE table_name = ''' || t.table_name || ''' and PARTITION_NAME = ''' || t.partition_name || ''''
                    ), '//text()')
                , 12, 10),
            'YYYY-MM-DD') AS high_value_t
    FROM user_tab_partitions t
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
) 
SELECT high_value_t
FROM date_partition
WHERE high_value_t > sysdate -1;
```

The problem is the Europe VS US format, and some complications...